# problem when a Grails domain class extends from a EJB

Tags: grails, ejb-3.0, instantiation, extends

When I has a grails domain class User that extends from a UserT class that is an EJB, in the User() instantiation throw an error. I understand not the cause of this problem, please help me for it and explain me why require the init method and where should be it. The follow is the error code:

```
Error creating bean with name 'gn.User': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [gn.User]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.jobs.users.UserT: method <init>()V not found
```

Comment: Ok ok, now the problem is the following:
Executing action [save] of controller [gn.UserController] caused exception: Unknown entity: gn.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: gn.User

But I has the gn.User as a Grails domain class and it is not a Bean class.

Answer (score 0):

Does the super class have a default constructor? I think it needs one.